# prevent 0 input after a negative sign

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So I have a feature where user can input a numbner and it will be converted to negative sign but user should not be able to add negative sign manually.

How do we solve it that user cannot or prevent 0 input after a negative sign , so if the value in the field is -565000 , if user add zero after the negative sign , it should not be allowed. And user should not be able to manually erase or remove the negative Sign

So inputs like 0 and other keys as long as not number is not allowed

For example , the current input is -900 , and user decided to move his cursor after the negative sign and press 0 or press letters like a , that should not be allowed

```
 <mat-form-field *ngIf="hasCashContribution === 'no'" appearance="fill" class="deal-form-date-picker opacity87" [ngClass]="{'enabled-input': hasCashContribution === 'no'}" style="padding-right: 16px;">
            <mat-label [ngClass]="{'alter-text-color': hasCashContribution === 'no'}">Payment</mat-label>
            <input matInput
              [(ngModel)]="cashContribution"
              class="alter-text-color"
              mask="separator.0"
              thousandSeparator=","
              [allowNegativeNumbers]="true"
              oninput="return event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'')"
              (input)="onInput($event)"
              readonly
             >
            <span matPrefix class="alter-text-color" *ngIf="hasCashContribution === 'no'">$</span>
          </mat-form-field>
```

```
 //prevent 0 inputs
  onInput(event: Event) {
    const inputElement = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    const inputValue = inputElement.value;
  
    if (event instanceof KeyboardEvent) {
      const key = event.key;
  
      // Check if input starts with a negative sign and a non-number key was pressed
      if (inputValue.startsWith('-') && !/^-?[0-9]/.test(key)) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    } else if (inputValue === '0' || /^0[^0-9]/.test(inputValue)) {
      inputElement.value = '';
    } else {
      const numericValue = parseFloat(inputValue.replace(/,/g, ''));
      if (!isNaN(numericValue)) {
        this.cashContribution = -numericValue;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in your script the input form is `readonly` so user cannot input anything.

You can change your `oninput` event in your `<input>` form to `onkeydown` with the following code:

```js
onkeydown="if (!(/([0-9]|Arrow(Down|Up|Left|Right)|Backspace)/).test(event.key) || ([0,1].includes(event.target.selectionStart) && (event.key == 0)) || (event.target.selectionStart == 1 && event.key == 'Backspace')) {event.preventDefault()}"
```

So your form will be:

```html
<mat-form-field *ngIf="hasCashContribution === 'no'" appearance="fill" class="deal-form-date-picker opacity87" [ngClass]="{'enabled-input': hasCashContribution === 'no'}" style="padding-right: 16px;">
    <mat-label [ngClass]="{'alter-text-color': hasCashContribution === 'no'}">Payment</mat-label>
    <input matInput
        [(ngModel)]="cashContribution"
        class="alter-text-color"
        mask="separator.0"
        thousandSeparator=",
        [allowNegativeNumbers]="true"
        onkeydown="if (!(/([0-9]|Arrow(Down|Up|Left|Right)|Backspace)/).test(event.key) || ([0,1].includes(event.target.selectionStart) && (event.key == 0)) || (event.target.selectionStart == 1 && event.key == 'Backspace')) {event.preventDefault()}"
        (input)="onInput($event)"
    />
    <span matPrefix class="alter-text-color" *ngIf="hasCashContribution === 'no'">$</span>
</mat-form-field>
```

That should work now.

However, I personally would not change the values to negative with a javascript script. I would rather add a negative sign (`-`) before the input form (for example using a `::beore` pseudo-element).

Also, I don't think you need the `[allowNegativeNumbers]` attribute.

Another point worth noting, is also that you are still not preventing users to be able to paste anything (including letters, special characters, etc.) into the input form.

Comment: it does not work Sir,  https://imgur.com/a/oolG0bw. As you can see here user inputs 500,000 and now it display -500,000 since it converts the value to negative..the issue is when I my cursor in the field after the negative sign and press 0 it removes the - sign . That is the current issue

Comment: @RavKumar According to the form script you provided, it works for me. 
Can you please provide the full script that renders the image you just provided so I can check what's the issue? From the image I cannot check anything.

Comment: that's all the hmtl code and ts code Sir

Comment: and you should not remove the onInput function SIr since it is the one that converts the value to a negative which I still needed

Comment: your code did not convert the input to a negative number that is why it works on your end SIR.

Comment: right now for example I have inputter 500,000 the value now is -500,000 and then I insert 0 or press 0 or any other letters like this  -0500,000 , the 0 removes the negative sign which now the -500,000 became 500,000 which is wrong, it should always be -500,000 and it should be allowed to input 0 or any keys on the first position

Comment: Yeah I understood that. 
I still cannot try your code though. I get all sorts of errors if I try to implement it on https://codesandbox.io.
Can you please provide a link to your working implementation on https://codesandbox.io so I can check it?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-form-field-iahpgr?file=app%2Fform-field-prefix-suffix-example.ts,app%2Fform-field-prefix-suffix-example.html try this

Comment: it is just a simple angular input field SIR , nothing complex on that

Comment: I edited again.

Comment: there is an issue Sir , I cant add a 0 after a single number for example I added -5 and then when I pressed to add 0 it does not work

Comment: If you are trying to add `0` after any number, it works for me.
Can you show an example please?

Comment: try to type in the field for example number 4 and then after that try to add 0

Comment: cant add 0 after a single digit number

Comment: Well, as I told you, I can. Try to type '40' in this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-form-field-fcedj5?file=app%2Fform-field-prefix-suffix-example.ts,app%2Fform-field-prefix-suffix-example.html). So, unless you provide me with an example that I can test, I cannot help you sorry.

Comment: All good Sir , thank you so much for the patience and effort. May God bless you.